# Why does Take() return more rows than specified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am querying a database with Entity Framework. To limit the results I am using Take(1000). The problem is that EF returns more than 1000 rows, and all entities  after #1000 do not contain correct data.

This is the table structure:

[image]

And the query looks like this:

```
var resultListTmp = db.TinglysEjendom.Where(x => x.EjdStatus == description)
    .Include(x => x.TinglysEjd_ESR.Select(y => y.ESR))               
    .Include(nameof(TingLysMatrikkel))
    .Take(amount).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

The problem is that all TinglysEjendom entities after #1000 do not have any TinglysMatrikkel relations, but in the database they do.

When removing:

```
.Include(x => x.TinglysEjd_ESR.Select(y => y.ESR))
```

from the query, EF returns correct number of rows.

The column MatrikkelNummer in the TinglysMatrikkel table can (amongst others) take the values:

æ
ø
å

Someone suggested it might be an i18n "Internationalization and localization" problem. Im not sure how this could be. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

LINQ translates the above query in to:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 

[UnionAll1].[EjdId] AS [C1], 

[UnionAll1].[EjdId1] AS [C2], 

[UnionAll1].[EjdType] AS [C3], 

[UnionAll1].[BygningsNr] AS [C4], 

[UnionAll1].[TimeshareNr] AS [C5], 

[UnionAll1].[AnpartsNr] AS [C6], 

[UnionAll1].[EjerLejNr] AS [C7], 

[UnionAll1].[Beskrivelse] AS [C8], 

[UnionAll1].[StreetBuildingIdentifier] AS [C9], 

[UnionAll1].[EjdStatus] AS [C10], 

[UnionAll1].[StatusTimestamp] AS [C11], 

[UnionAll1].[IAbonnement] AS [C12], 

[UnionAll1].[AbonnementOpretAttempts] AS [C13], 

[UnionAll1].[AbonnementsId] AS [C14], 

[UnionAll1].[BestemtFastEjendomsNummer] AS [C15], 

[UnionAll1].[UpdateToken] AS [C16], 

[UnionAll1].[FaellesEjendomIdentifikator] AS [C17], 

[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C18], 

[UnionAll1].[ESRId] AS [C19], 

[UnionAll1].[ESRId1] AS [C20], 

[UnionAll1].[EjdId2] AS [C21], 

[UnionAll1].[Passiv] AS [C22], 

[UnionAll1].[ESRId2] AS [C23], 

[UnionAll1].[EjdId3] AS [C24], 

[UnionAll1].[ESRId3] AS [C25], 

[UnionAll1].[ESR_Kommune] AS [C26], 

[UnionAll1].[ESR_EjdNummer] AS [C27], 

[UnionAll1].[UdgaaetCognito] AS [C28], 

[UnionAll1].[Status] AS [C29], 

[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C30], 

[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C31], 

[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C32], 

[UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C33]

FROM  (SELECT 

    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[ESRId1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 

    [Limit1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 

    [Limit1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId1], 

    [Limit1].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 

    [Limit1].[BygningsNr] AS [BygningsNr], 

    [Limit1].[TimeshareNr] AS [TimeshareNr], 

    [Limit1].[AnpartsNr] AS [AnpartsNr], 

    [Limit1].[EjerLejNr] AS [EjerLejNr], 

    [Limit1].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 

    [Limit1].[StreetBuildingIdentifier] AS [StreetBuildingIdentifier], 

    [Limit1].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 

    [Limit1].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 

    [Limit1].[IAbonnement] AS [IAbonnement], 

    [Limit1].[AbonnementOpretAttempts] AS [AbonnementOpretAttempts], 

    [Limit1].[AbonnementsId] AS [AbonnementsId], 

    [Limit1].[BestemtFastEjendomsNummer] AS [BestemtFastEjendomsNummer], 

    [Limit1].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 

    [Limit1].[FaellesEjendomIdentifikator] AS [FaellesEjendomIdentifikator], 

    [Join1].[ESRId1] AS [ESRId], 

    [Join1].[ESRId1] AS [ESRId1], 

    [Join1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId2], 

    [Join1].[Passiv] AS [Passiv], 

    [Join1].[ESRId1] AS [ESRId2], 

    [Join1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId3], 

    [Join1].[ESRId2] AS [ESRId3], 

    [Join1].[ESR_Kommune] AS [ESR_Kommune], 

    [Join1].[ESR_EjdNummer] AS [ESR_EjdNummer], 

    [Join1].[UdgaaetCognito] AS [UdgaaetCognito], 

    [Join1].[Status] AS [Status], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 

    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 

    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5]

    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1000) 

        [Extent1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 

        [Extent1].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 

        [Extent1].[BygningsNr] AS [BygningsNr], 

        [Extent1].[TimeshareNr] AS [TimeshareNr], 

        [Extent1].[AnpartsNr] AS [AnpartsNr], 

        [Extent1].[EjerLejNr] AS [EjerLejNr], 

        [Extent1].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 

        [Extent1].[StreetBuildingIdentifier] AS [StreetBuildingIdentifier], 

        [Extent1].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 

        [Extent1].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 

        [Extent1].[IAbonnement] AS [IAbonnement], 

        [Extent1].[AbonnementOpretAttempts] AS [AbonnementOpretAttempts], 

        [Extent1].[AbonnementsId] AS [AbonnementsId], 

        [Extent1].[BestemtFastEjendomsNummer] AS [BestemtFastEjendomsNummer], 

        [Extent1].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 

        [Extent1].[FaellesEjendomIdentifikator] AS [FaellesEjendomIdentifikator]

        FROM [dbo].[TinglysEjendom] AS [Extent1]

        WHERE [Extent1].[EjdStatus] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[ESRId] AS [ESRId1], [Extent2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], [Extent2].[Passiv] AS [Passiv], [Extent3].[ESRId] AS [ESRId2], [Extent3].[ESR_Kommune] AS [ESR_Kommune], [Extent3].[ESR_EjdNummer] AS [ESR_EjdNummer], [Extent3].[UdgaaetCognito] AS [UdgaaetCognito], [Extent3].[Status] AS [Status]

        FROM  [dbo].[TinglysEjd_ESR] AS [Extent2]

        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ESR] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ESRId] = [Extent3].[ESRId] ) AS [Join1] ON [Limit1].[EjdId] = [Join1].[EjdId]

UNION ALL

    SELECT 

    2 AS [C1], 

    [Limit2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 

    [Limit2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId1], 

    [Limit2].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 

    [Limit2].[BygningsNr] AS [BygningsNr], 

    [Limit2].[TimeshareNr] AS [TimeshareNr], 

    [Limit2].[AnpartsNr] AS [AnpartsNr], 

    [Limit2].[EjerLejNr] AS [EjerLejNr], 

    [Limit2].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 

    [Limit2].[StreetBuildingIdentifier] AS [StreetBuildingIdentifier], 

    [Limit2].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 

    [Limit2].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 

    [Limit2].[IAbonnement] AS [IAbonnement], 

    [Limit2].[AbonnementOpretAttempts] AS [AbonnementOpretAttempts], 

    [Limit2].[AbonnementsId] AS [AbonnementsId], 

    [Limit2].[BestemtFastEjendomsNummer] AS [BestemtFastEjendomsNummer], 

    [Limit2].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 

    [Limit2].[FaellesEjendomIdentifikator] AS [FaellesEjendomIdentifikator], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 

    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C5], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 

    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 

    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C11], 

    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C12], 

    [Extent5].[EjdId] AS [EjdId2], 

    [Extent5].[LandsEjerlavKode] AS [LandsEjerlavKode], 

    [Extent5].[MatrikkelNummer] AS [MatrikkelNummer], 

    [Extent5].[EjdId] AS [EjdId3]

    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1000) 

        [Extent4].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 

        [Extent4].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 

        [Extent4].[BygningsNr] AS [BygningsNr], 

        [Extent4].[TimeshareNr] AS [TimeshareNr], 

        [Extent4].[AnpartsNr] AS [AnpartsNr], 

        [Extent4].[EjerLejNr] AS [EjerLejNr], 

        [Extent4].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 

        [Extent4].[StreetBuildingIdentifier] AS [StreetBuildingIdentifier], 

        [Extent4].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 

        [Extent4].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 

        [Extent4].[IAbonnement] AS [IAbonnement], 

        [Extent4].[AbonnementOpretAttempts] AS [AbonnementOpretAttempts], 

        [Extent4].[AbonnementsId] AS [AbonnementsId], 

        [Extent4].[BestemtFastEjendomsNummer] AS [BestemtFastEjendomsNummer], 

        [Extent4].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 

        [Extent4].[FaellesEjendomIdentifikator] AS [FaellesEjendomIdentifikator]

        FROM [dbo].[TinglysEjendom] AS [Extent4]

        WHERE [Extent4].[EjdStatus] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit2]

    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TingLysMatrikkel] AS [Extent5] ON [Limit2].[EjdId] = [Extent5].[EjdId]) AS [UnionAll1]

ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[EjdId1] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'HentData'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a somewhat unreliable query at the C# part. That said, it's up to Entity Framework to translate it to SQL that does what you asked, and it's failing to do that. It may be worth reporting as a bug if it hasn't been already.

If you look closely in your SQL, you'll find two separate queries using `TOP (1000)` combined by `UNION ALL`. However, neither of those queries is using any `ORDER BY`, therefore there's nothing preventing SQL Server from picking a different set of 1000 records, which it may do if e.g. it can use a different index for the first part of the query compared to the second.

You should be able to work around it by specifying *which* first 1000 records you want returned. If you don't care about the order, just order them by ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I put a ORDER BY on the query and that solved the problem. I will look into filing it as a bug.

Comment: If it should be of any interest, there are two indexes on the TinglysEjendom table: #1 - Non Unique, Non Clustered #2 - Clustered.

Comment: @Kenci did you report this as a bug? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Jacques actually never had the time to report it :(